# `No value provided for required argument: id` error in graph ql database

Tags: python, graphql

### Question

- I am tryting to download data from a cryptocurrency exchange ["perpetual protocol"](https://perp.exchange/t/AAVE:USDC)
- The API document page is [here](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/perpetual-protocol/perp-position-subgraph?query=List%20FundingRateUpdated%20events), which lets you see how the API works.
- Since my main programming language is Python, I am using it to download data but I got the following error message.
  `{'errors': [{'locations': [{'line': 0, 'column': 0}], 'message': 'No value provided for required argument: id'}]}`.
- Can anyone tell me how to fix this error to download data, please?

```
import request

timestamp = 1607904000

graphql_endpoint = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/perpetual-protocol/perp-position-subgraph'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

fundingRateUpdatedEvent_query = """query {
                            fundingRateUpdatedEvent(first: 1000, orderBy:timestamp,orderDirection:asc, where:{timestamp_gt: %i}) {
                                    id
                                    amm
                                    rate
                                    underlyingPrice
                                    timestamp
                        }}""" % (timestamp)

request_result = requests.post(graphql_endpoint, json={'query': fundingRateUpdatedEvent_query}, headers=headers)
if request_result.status_code == 200:
    request_result.json()['data']['fundingRateUpdatedEvents']
else:
    raise Exception(f"GraphQL query failed to run by returning code of {request.status_code}.")
```

- It is weird to me because the following codes below has no problem working. The only difference is the contents in query statement.

```
timestamp = 1607904000

graphql_endpoint = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/perpetual-protocol/perp-position-subgraph'
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

positionChanged_query = """query {
                            positionChangedEvents(first: 1000, orderBy:timestamp,orderDirection:asc, where:{timestamp_gt: %i}) {
                                    id
                                    trader
                                    timestamp
                                    amm
                                    margin
                                    positionNotional
                                    exchangedPositionSize
                                    fee
                                    positionSizeAfter
                                    realizedPnl
                                    unrealizedPnlAfter
                                    badDebt
                                    liquidationPenalty
                                    spotPrice
                                    fundingPayment
                        }}""" % (timestamp)

request_result = requests.post(graphql_endpoint, json={'query': positionChanged_query}, headers=headers)
print(request_result)
if request_result.status_code == 200:
    print(request_result.json())
    request_result.json()['data']['positionChangedEvents']
else:
    raise Exception(f"GraphQL query failed to run by returning code of {request.status_code}.")
```

Comment: test queries in playground **before coding** ... **use variables**, not string manipulations https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ... recreate working playground request in python - comparing network request bodies

Comment: @xdam can you put your comments in another way, please? I can't understand what you meant by "before coding ... use variables". Do I have ... in my codes?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pluralize the entity you are querying:

`fundingRateUpdatedEvents`

I believe we encountered the same issue using the graph!